# How accurate is GitHub traffic analytics?

Tags: github, analytics

It seems to me that GitHub analytics is not very accurate.

I have some repositories with 1-3 visits in 14 days, and one that gets 5-20 visitors a day.

Even for repositories that get little to no outside traffic, I might visit them a few times a week and still, analytics says 0 visits for those days.

I'm questioning my sanity a bit, as I've searched for but not found, others having the same curious experience.

I would love some clarification because I feel like there is something I'm missing... or likely there are some circumstances where a visit isn't logged... I suppose I can test this myself but would be happy for any insight you have to offer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While setting up google analytics for my web-page, I realized the problem is that I use adblockers, which also blocks all trackers. So, they weren't tracking my activity at any point.

Thanks for sharing this "duh!" moment, with me.

Answer (score 0):

Self-visits are included in GitHub traffic analytics.

> **Q:** Do the numbers in the traffic graphs include your own views? What
>   about the view of contributors?
>
> **GitHub support:**
>   Yes, the numbers include everyone's views
>   including repository owners and contributors. There's no way to filter
>   this information at the moment but we can definitely add that as a
>   feature request for the team to consider. Your own views are counted on repository traffic graphs, and there is no way to filter out your own page views of those of other repository contributors

Comment: And yet i can tell that they are not always